# WooCommerce product title cannot be removed on the single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I cannot remove the default title of WooCommerce product on single page.

The title doesn't have any tags for me to hide it via css.

I also tried using

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

but still not working.

Does anyone have a solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try in the following way

```php
function customise_product_page() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'customise_product_page' );
```

Comment: that is not the product title added through `woocommerce_single_product_summary`. 
It seems to me previously specifically added from your theme

Comment: Well, there seem to be more problems with your theme, see: https://crossfithurstville.com.au/wp-content/themes/crossfit/. There is no hook that will solve your problem.